# Merge two objects of same type

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

I have two objects:

`deviceConfigInfo` and `deviceStatusInfo`

Both contain an array of `devices` (so theres a third `device` object actually).

For each `device` returned in `deviceConfigInfo` there are these properties:

- `uuid`
- `name`
- `somethingElse`
- `lookAnotherOne`

and for `deviceStatusInfo`

- `uuid`
- `name`
- `somethingElse`
- `someStatusInfo`
- `someMoreStuff`

(If you hadn't guessed, I just made up some random properties)

So back to that third object I mentioned, `device`, I created it with all the properties combined. Now, my question is, say the `deviceStatusInfo` gets updated, how can I update the `device` object without losing the "old" data that isn't overwritten (in this case, the `lookAnotherOne` property).

Does it have to be a manual process of getting the device with the matching `uuid` and then updating each of the properties for `deviceStatusInfo` or is there a quicker way of doing this? Imagine there were loads of properties.

Hopefully this makes sense. If it helps, I am using [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) to create the objects/models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that Mantle has the following function which I was able to use:

`mergeValueForKey:fromModel:`

So in my `device` model, I added two functions:

- `mergeConfigInfoKeysFromModel:`
- `mergeStatusInfoKeysFromModel:`

These functions have access to an array that contains `NSString` values representing the properties/keys. There is one array for the `configInfo` and another for `statusInfo` properties/keys.

I then loop through the keys and use `valueForKey` to check it has an actual value. If it does, I then call the `mergeValueForKey:fromModel:`.

Example Code:

```
- (void)mergeConfigInfoKeysFromModel:(MTLModel *)model
{
    NSArray *configInfoKeys = @[@"uuid", @"name", @"somethingElse", @"lookAnotherOne"];

    for (NSString *key in configInfoKeys) {
        if ([model valueForKey:key]) {
            [self mergeValueForKey:key fromModel:model];
        }
    }
}
```

All I have to do now, is call the appropriate merge function on the `device` object when I get an update, passing over the updated `device` object. Just as below:

```
[self.device mergeConfigInfoKeysFromModel:deviceUpdate];
```